# What design patterns work well with lambdas?

Tags: design-patterns, lambda

What design patterns have you found work well with lambda expressions/functions?

Comment: To the close voters: Why is this "Not a Real Question?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambdas are actively used in IoC containers and DI (for example mock frameworks) nowadays

I can see following GoF patterns in this area:

Moq is using `Proxy` pattern with active use of lambdas; for example:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true);
```

You can find that lambdas help to implement `Singleton` pattern in [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) containers, for example [autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), without limiting yourself in testability, like usual Singleton does:

```
builder.Register(c => new MyClass()).SingleInstance();
```

And `Factory Method` pattern by means of proving a constructor call with parameters as type registration:

```
builder
    .Register(c => new ObjectContainer(ConnectionStrings.CustomerDB))
    .As<IObjectContainer>()
    .Named("CustomerObjectContainer");
```

Also

`Expression <TDelegate>` class is also closely related to `Interpreter` pattern

Answer (score 1):

There's a few situations where I see them used a fair bit:

For one, they're great for high-level iteration over collections. Often, we just need to apply a tranformation of some sort to a list or a tree or something. Using lambdas makes for easy-to-use and compact code for collection processing. For a randomly pointless example (in C# using LINQ):

```
var list = new List<int>();
//...
list.Where(x => x < 10).Aggregate( (current, total) => total + current * current );
```

Without lambdas, this kind of code would be hideously and unnecessarily large.

They're also handy when using API that revolve around callbacks, as there are many times when we only need to use a callback once. It sucks having to write full functions that are intended for one-time usage, since that is just extra code that clutters namespaces.

A last design pattern comes to you from JavaScript. I'm not sure if this applies to lambdas in general, as I don't know if closures are a required component of lambdas. But since many languages allow lambdas to close over variables, I'll mention it anyways.

As you may or may not know, JavaScript is capable of object oriented design via prototype-based inheritance. But one drawback is that it has no concept of data abstraction. However, it was discovered a while back that lambdas could actually be used to provide data abstraction. By using the closures of anonymous functions (which really are lambdas), we can accomplish this:

```
function Rectangle(width, height) {
    this.getWidth = function() { return width; }
    this.getHeight = function() { return height; }
}
```

Since the closures defined by `getWidth` and `getHeight` include the `width` and `height` parameters, the parameters are still usable from the methods. But they are not maintained anywhere else, so no other code has access to them once the `Rectangle` constructor exits. Therefore, `width` and `height` are now private to `Rectangle` and accessible only via the provided accessor methods.

Aside from those, I'd say that lambdas just have a nice theoretical feel to them. Languages that support them feel more complete, less restrictive, and less cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

Monadic patterns are completely based on lambda's and can only be implemented when using lambda's. 
Explanation of monads in C#:
http://ericlippert.com/category/monads/

Monads in C++:
http://bartoszmilewski.com/2011/07/11/monads-in-c/

Python:
http://www.valuedlessons.com/2008/01/monads-in-python-with-nice-syntax.html